# How do I copy and paste all cookies related to a website?

Tags: cookies, xss

I am learning some basic concepts about XSS and now I want to see what's gonna happen if I copy all cookies related to one site and paste it in a clean browser tab (e.g. open a incognito tab or open another browser).

What's the proper way to do this? What tools do you guys use?

---

I've tried copying my own cookies with `document.cookie` and then open an incognito window, open the same website, then in the console tab `document.cookie = 'the whole cookie string'`.

But problems are:

1. some subdomain cookies are not displayed by `document.cookie`.
2. I can't send the copied cookies from the initial reuqest(I don't know whether if this will affect the result I am gonna see)
3. I have to manually copy and add e.g. http only cookies.

Anyway, is there an all-in-one solution for this, instead of manually editing the cookies?

Answer (score 1):

I never copy *all* cookies, I copy just the session cookie, and I use the [developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector) of the browser for that.

If you want to copy all cookies, you may want to try [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en) which can import and export all cookies as JSON.

Comment: I don't know which key-value pair would be enough for authentication/view private information, so I intend to copy all cookies... Thank you let me try the extension first. :)

Answer (score 0):

EditThisCookie extension allows copying cookies of the domain of current url/tab. It does not allow copying cookies of other domains that were loaded in the current tab.

So, for example if you are on tab "https://www.google.com", then in Developer Tool --> Application --> Cookies, you will see more than two frames in cookies section as highlighted in below screenshot:

[image]

If you need to copy/export all the cookies that were loaded for the current tab, then you can use [StorageAce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storageace/cpbgcbmddckpmhfbdckeolkkhkjjmplo) chrome extension, but make sure the "All Frames" toggle is on as shown below:

[image]